# Force module to parse dom on filter return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fitvids

I have a filter returning an youtube embed that has a wrapper linked to a module. My issue is on filter return the module never gets applied to the returned html, wondering how I can force it to watch/recompile.

**Filter:**

```
angular
    .module( "filters" )
    .filter( "youtubeFilter", [ "$filter", "$sce",
        function ( $filter, $sce )
            {
                "use strict";

                return function( message )
                {
                    var re = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig;

                    message = message.replace(re, "<div fitvids><iframe width='640' height='360' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/$1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>");

                    // message = "";

                    return $sce.trustAsHtml( message );
                } ;
            }
    ] );
```

**Module:**

```
angular.module('fitVids', []).directive('fitVids', [function() {
    'use strict';

    if (!document.getElementById('fit-vids-style')) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        var cssStyles = '&shy;<style>.fluid-width-video-wrapper{width:100%;position:relative;padding:0;}.fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe,.fluid-width-video-wrapper object,.fluid-width-video-wrapper embed {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}</style>';
        div.className = 'fit-vids-style';
        div.id = 'fit-vids-style';
        div.style.display = 'none';
        div.innerHTML = cssStyles;
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            var selectors = [
                "iframe[src*='player.vimeo.com']",
                "iframe[src*='youtube.com']",
                "iframe[src*='youtube-nocookie.com']",
                "iframe[src*='kickstarter.com'][src*='video.html']",
                "object",
                "embed"
            ];

            var videos;

            if (attr.customSelector) {
                selectors.push(attr.customSelector);
            }

            videos = element[0].querySelectorAll(selectors.join(','));

            angular.forEach(videos, function (item) {

                var $item = angular.element(item);
                var height, width, aspectRatio;

                if (item.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'embed' &&
                        ($item.parent().tagName === 'object' && $item.parent().length) ||
                        $item.parent().hasClass('.fluid-width-video-wrapper')) {
                    return;
                }

                height = (item.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'object' || $item.attr('height')) ? parseInt($item.attr('height'), 10) : $item.height();
                width = !isNaN(parseInt($item.attr('width'), 10)) ? parseInt($item.attr('width'), 10) : $item.width();
                aspectRatio = height / width;

                if (!$item.attr('id')) {
                    var videoID = 'fitvid' + Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
                    $item.attr('id', videoID);
                }

                $item.wrap('<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" />').parent().css('padding-top', (aspectRatio * 100) + "%");
                $item.removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');

            });

        }
    };

}]);
```